# sql '=' operator returns unexpected result

Tags: php, sql

here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tx_branddata_info` 
WHERE  `brand_title` =  'BOEHLER'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

it returns

[image]

but the expected result is the first one.any one have any solution other than changing the collation.

Comment: use LIKE Operator.

Comment: is `brand_title` a `NVARCHAR` coulmn?

Comment: What SQL server is this...? MySQL I presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems `brand_title` 's following **latin1_german2_ci** rules (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-we-sets.html):

```
Ä = AE
Ö = OE
Ü = UE
ß = ss
```

Check field character set and change, if you can obviously, to, imho, utf8mb4.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tx_branddata_info` 
WHERE  BINARY  `brand_title` = 'BOEHLER'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

My table collation is latin1_german2_ci.It's rules are following:

```
Ä = AE
Ö = OE
Ü = UE
ß = ss
```

So i changed the query as follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tx_branddata_info` 
WHERE  `brand_title` LIKE  'BOEHLER'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now it's working fine as `'Like'` is doing a character by character comparison.